# Does `sl` ever show the current directory?

Tags: linux

For those out of the loop, `sl` is a humourous command line tool that is meant to trip people up if they mistype `ls`. When invoked it prints a Steam Locomotive. For example:

```
                          (  ) (@@) ( )  (@)  ()    @@    O     @     O     @      O
                     (@@@)
                 (    )
              (@@@@)

            (   )
         ====        ________                ___________
     _D _|  |_______/        \__I_I_____===__|_________|
      |(_)---  |   H\________/ |   |        =|___ ___|      _________________
      /     |  |   H  |  |     |   |         ||_| |_||     _|                \_____A
     |      |  |   H  |__--------------------| [___] |   =|                        |
     | ________|___H__/__|_____/[][]~\_______|       |   -|                        |
     |/ |   |-----------I_____I [][] []  D   |=======|____|________________________|_
   __/ =| o |=-O=====O=====O=====O \ ____Y___________|__|__________________________|_
    |/-=|___|=    ||    ||    ||    |_____/~\___/          |_D__D__D_|  |_D__D__D_|
     \_/      \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/      \_/               \_/   \_/    \_/   \_/
```

However, in the man page for `sl`, it states the following bug:

```
BUGS
        It rarely shows contents of current directory.
```

**So, the question remains, are there some conditions, under which `sl` actually *does* show the current directory?**

Comment: The simple answer is no. 8-)

Comment: +1 for introducing me to a very useful _utility_ I'd been unaware of for decades.

Comment: @slm We've assertained that, so I've put in a bug that addresses this critical issue: [#9](https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl/issues/9)

Comment: `alias l='ls'`. Fixed.

Comment: It says it rarely shows the _contents_ of the directory. So I presume they mean if you have files like `|      |  |   H  |__--------------------| [___] |   =|                        |`, sl shows them.

Comment: Critical issue? Here's a fix...uninstall it and `alias sl=ls`.

Comment: often it also work with the command `LS` in capital

Comment: Building on what @MrLister said - if you have a text file which contains the picture of the locomotive, then `sl` _will_ show the "contents of the current directory"...

Comment: @MrLister You should post that as an answer. To me that makes perfect sense. More so than the "typo" answer does.

Comment: btw, you jump of this train of death with ctr-z. :)

Comment: Unless you cheat with `sl > /dev/null && ls`, I think the answer is no.

Comment: Pull Request inc: https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl/pull/11

Comment: I have been a Unix/Linux sysadmin for 14 years and had never heard of this incredible tool. It's amazing how much there is to learn.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJBNBHQv_c0

Comment: @MrLister that is the most ingenuous presumption I've seen in *years*.

Comment: By the way, have you ever tried `sl --help`?

Answer (score 193):

As far as I know, the only condition under which `sl` shows the current directory is when you mistype it as `ls`.

Comment: +1 Humorous, but I'm hoping for a more authoritative answer.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - perhaps you're waiting for LegoEmperor to weigh in?

Answer (score 41):

- Lemma: `sl` prints a steam locomotive
- Lemma: Valid *file names* cannot contain forward slashes (although *paths* can)
- Lemma: The steam locomotive contains forward slashes:

  ```
  $ touch '                          (  ) (@@) ( )  (@)  ()    @@    O     @     O     @      O
  >                      (@@@)
  >                  (    )
  >               (@@@@)
  > 
  >             (   )
  >          ====        ________                ___________
  >      _D _|  |_______/        \__I_I_____===__|_________|
  >       |(_)---  |   H\________/ |   |        =|___ ___|      _________________
  >       /     |  |   H  |  |     |   |         ||_| |_||     _|                \_____A
  >      |      |  |   H  |__--------------------| [___] |   =|                        |
  >      | ________|___H__/__|_____/[][]~\_______|       |   -|                        |
  >      |/ |   |-----------I_____I [][] []  D   |=======|____|________________________|_
  >    __/ =| o |=-O=====O=====O=====O \ ____Y___________|__|__________________________|_
  >     |/-=|___|=    ||    ||    ||    |_____/~\___/          |_D__D__D_|  |_D__D__D_|
  >      \_/      \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/      \_/               \_/   \_/    \_/   \_/'
  touch: cannot touch ‘[...]’: No such file or directory
  ```

Conclusion: `sl` never shows the current directory. QED.

Comment: Why is it not a valid file name?  Too long?

Comment: It contains several `/`'es, which are not allowed in Unix filenames.

Comment: You could always create the intermediate directories -- but then it wouldn't be showing (just) the contents of the *current* directory.

Comment: If you did a `mkdir -p "$(dirname "$(sl)")"` you could do `touch "$(sl)"`. Of course, you might be testing the limits of your OS/FS. And have fun cleaning that up.

Comment: I don't know if this counts, but there have been buggy programs that allowed you to rename a file to one with slashes in. Konqueror 3 comes to mind. Then you could have files with those exact names.

Comment: @MrLister Surely that would only be possible if the filesystem also had a bug in it to allow such files to be created. Do you have a reference?

Comment: That's the first time I see something useful in Windows using backslash as path separator... Can we run it under Windows? Ohh... just seeing that it also contains \ ... </enthusiastic mode>

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: Not really. Windows supports both `/` and ``\``, and they mean the same thing.

Comment: @xfix But, can they both be used in filenames then, if escaped in some way? To contradict the proof above, we need to use the whole multiline train as a filename, but that contains `/` and `\` - I have not much hope left that Windows supports both as part of a plain file name :) I shoud just accept the proof, maybe!

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: No, they cannot be used in file names. ``c:\windows/system32\notepad.exe`` is perfectly fine path in Windows.

Comment: On OS X, you can get the Finder to show you "filenames" with slashes in them. They really contain colons (`:`), which were directory separators in the ancestors of OS X; the Finder visualizes them as slashes.

Comment: If you have a file called `H` (for instance), then `sl` does indeed show it. It's just that it also shows a lot of other things. :-)

Comment: @Kevin i tried it: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘\033[?1049h\033[1;33r\033[m\033(B\033[4l\ [many many bytes] 033[1P\n\033[1P\n\033[1P\n    \033[1K\r\033[1P\n\033[1P\n\033[1P\n\033[1P\n=| o |=-~~\\  ’: File name too long`. So at least on btrfs it doesn't work.

Comment: oh yikes, before it gave up though it did create a pretty deep tree!

Answer (score 37):

Here's a patch to fix that bug :)

```
diff --git a/sl.c b/sl.c
index 2eeceb3..f2213ad 100644
--- a/sl.c
+++ b/sl.c
@@ -37,6 +37,7 @@
 #include <curses.h>
 #include <signal.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
+#include <stdlib.h>
 #include "sl.h"

 int ACCIDENT  = 0;
@@ -71,6 +72,13 @@ void option(char *str)
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     int x, i;
+    
+    srand(time(NULL));
+    if(rand() % 100 < 10)
+    {
+       /* 10% chance of directory listing :) */
+       execv("/bin/ls", argv);
+    }

     for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    if (*argv[i] == '-') {
```

Comment: Oh lord. You sir are a scholar and a genius.

Comment: Please... please... [file a pull request for that patch](https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl/pulls)

Comment: Y'know, I actually have no idea how to do that? I don't use github myself except as a web-based download portal for other people's software. You can do that if you like. I officially disclaim all copyright on the above code and place it in the public domain.

Comment: +1, but that's not exactly 10% - `rand()` ["Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX,"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) which is library-dependent but may not be divisible by 100.

Comment: @devnull, your edit is wrong: `exit` is unreachable (no fork). @l0b0, that's the point of the modulo. The link you provided yourself uses the exact same example: there is a 10% chance of getting 0-9 (`< 10`) out of the 0-99 (`% 100`) range provided the distribution is uniform. *Why am I doing this.*

Comment: @tne You are right; rolling back.

Comment: Technically, execx() functions can return. From `man 3 exec`: "If any of the exec() functions returns, an error will have occurred.  The return value is -1, and the global variable errno will be set to indicate the error."

Comment: Of course, if `execv("/bin/ls", argv)` fails, you've got bigger problems than seeing a steam locomotive you weren't expecting.

Comment: @tne The modulo doesn't solve that. For example, if you use a `rand()` which returns a number between 0 and 109, there's an almost 2% chance of `rand() % 100 < 10`. With a minimum range of 32767 the difference is pretty small, but not zero.

Comment: @l0b0 I think you mean 20%? `2/11 == 0.181818...` But yes, point taken. The actual chance of getting less than ten back from the modulo is more like `0.1 + (10/67)*(67/32768) ~= 10.03%` if rand is returning a non-negative signed short with something approximating a uniform random distribution.

Comment: @lonoclast Brigham: You're entirely right. I think it's about time the `sl` project had its own flame war about whether it should fallback to the train behavior or error-out if `ls` can't be found/executed for whatever reason :). @l0b0: I stand corrected, you were one step ahead of me the whole time. (I actually misread your "library-independent" sentence; didn't realize you were talking about `RAND_MAX` and thought you were talking about the result for some reason, which is why it sounded so weird.) It's been a good run guys, but I hereby resign from the project. Too many disagreements.

Answer (score 24):

You can check the source code here - https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl, alas there is no other options other than the ones documented and sadly nothing that will actually print the names of files.

So it looks like [@sfyn's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124818/48083) is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have [lodged a ticket with the developer to see if this can be resolved](https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl/issues/9).

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, indeed a critical issue.

Comment: Possibly the biggest bug since Heartbleed!

Answer (score 13):

Note that I0b0's answer is only a proof that `sl` will never display all and *only* the current directory listing. However, there are circumstances in which `sl` will display the current directory listing together with additional 'information'.

For example, in an empty directory:

```
$ touch '                          (  ) (@@) ( )  (@)  ()    @@    O     @     O     @      O'
$ touch '                   (@@@)'
$ touch '                  (    )'
$ touch '              (@@@@)'
$ touch '            (   )'
$ sl
```

will on the first six lines list the contents of the directory, and on the remaining 10 lines will conveniently embellish this listing with  an image of a train (without smoke).

Comment: Or, the current directory could be an empty set.  In which case all the (non-existent) files are displayed along with a picture of a train.  :-)

Answer (score 8):

I know that [Lego Stormtroopr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53306/lego-stormtroopr) has [logged a ticket](https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl/issues/9) so that the critical issue can be addressed.  Who knows much time it might take for a fix to be rolled out?

As such, I've provided a workaround so that the impact due to the grave issue is minimized.  You can create a shell function `sl` that would execute `sl`:

```
sl() {
  ((RANDOM%42)) && command sl || ls;
}
```

Now invoking `sl` will, sporadically, list the directory contents.

Answer (score 2):

If you alias it to `ls`, it'll print the current directory - in fact, once I stopped laughing at the steam engine locomotive, I added that to my list of aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `sl` will act just like ls if you set up the appropriate alias in bash or whatever shell you are using!

I actually have several alias for ls including

```
alias ls='ls -FG'
alias ll='ls -lFG'
```

so thanks for the suggestion — I will add

```
alias sl='ls -FG'
```

(Not that I ever remember typing `sl` but then I tend to us `ll` or `lh`!)

Answer (score 1):

You could always review it's source code for yourself, and you would see under no condition does it ever perform the actual `ls` command nor display directories.

https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl

The source is rather simple actually. Even if you are "not a coder" you should still be able to understand most of it.

I believe the "bug" you posted above is really just in jest (and to cause discussion like this lol)

Answer (score -1):

You could do like I do also...

> > mv /usr/games/sl /usr/games/sl-OLD
> >
> > mv /usr/games/LS /usr/games/LS-OLD
> >
> > nano /usr/games/sl
> >
> > > Paste the following:
> > >
> > > > #!/bin/bash
> > > >
> > > > echo "YOU TYPED 'sl' INSTEAD OF 'ls'!"
> > > >
> > > > /usr/games/sl-old
> > > >
> > > > echo "Guess I can list it anyways..."
> > > >
> > > > /bin/ls
> >
> > Press CTRL+X to exit and Y to save.
> >
> > nano /usr/games/LS
> >
> > > Paste the following:
> > >
> > > > #!/bin/bash
> > > >
> > > > echo "YOU TYPED 'LS' INSTEAD OF 'ls'!"
> > > >
> > > > /usr/games/sl-old
> > > >
> > > > echo "Guess I can list it anyways..."
> > > >
> > > > /bin/ls
> >
> > Press CTRL+X to exit and Y to save.

P.S: You're welcome for reviving this.. searching to "sl linux command" still brings this thread up, so I thought I would give a real answer as to how I made it list the files...